# Get records based on other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm very new to Ruby and have no idea to do this. I need to create a select based on 2 tables: A and B. Both are ActiveRecord.

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :a
end
```

There are `A` records with no `B` records associated. I would like to get those records with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails, the `belongs_to` association will mean that table `a` has a field called `b_id`. This means that the `A` table has direct access to it's association to `B`.

To get the `A` records without any `B` attached, run `A.where(b_id: nil)`, this will return an array of all `A` records without a `B`

Edit: As coorasse stated, you can also just run `A.where(b: nil)`, which Rails will interpret as `A.where(b_id: nil)`.

Comment: What about A.joins(:B).where(:B => nil) ?

Comment: Joins grabs the `A` records that have a `B` associated and joins the two (rails does an `INNER JOIN`), so `B` will never be nil. But `joins` can be very useful when you want to grab associations without grabbing those with `nil`!

Comment: using your approach the query running on terminal is finished after few seconds.

Comment: @learner `A.joins(:b)`  already means that there will only be `A` records with at least one associated `B` record

Answer (score 4):

Yet another option is to use [`includes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes):

```
A.includes(:b).where(bs: { id: nil })
```

It will make a single query to database.

Comment: What is bs? Honestly I don't know

Comment: @learner into the `include` you put the association name (`:b` in your case), into where clause you always put the real database table name no matter how the model is called.

Comment: Good to know. Ruby is hard by the way.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve A records with a B record associated with:

```
A.joins(:B)
```

if you need all A records which don't have an association with B you can execute:

```
A.where(B: nil)
```

Comment: Right. I wonder if I have another restriction like a specific field value. For example b.user_name="Bryan".

Comment: Running this on rails console throws PG::UndefinedColumn exception

Comment: @learner because you can not use it in the form this answer showed it literally. You should either use Chris Brisson's answer: `A.where(b_id: nil)` or `A.where(b: nil)` or what I showed :)

Answer (score 2):

Hhhmm..you can do something like,

```
unassociated_ids = A.pluck(:id) - B.pluck(:a_id).uniq
A.where(id: unassociated_ids)
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: this is 3 requests to database - very inefficient.

Comment: I know, but i suppose it is one time operation, for clearing out stale data..if it needs to be included in the code then definitely not recommended... @Andrey Deineko

Comment: Nothing justifies 3 calls to DB when single one is possible instead. Especially, when it is much more easy/shorter/clearer to make it.

Comment: Yes bro..thanx for better solution..I got upvotes for the only reason it was an early reply i guess..other solutions are definitely better if they work for the asker..